# Remove single quote raw query in sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to do the following query in sequelize:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title,body)
    -> AGAINST ('+MySQL -YourSQL' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

this is my attempt:

```
var rawQuery = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE MATCH (email) AGAINST ('?*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)";

                return sequelize.query(rawQuery, {
                        replacements: [text],
                        type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
                    }).then(function(user) {
                        return user;
                });
```

The problem is that I get an error because what I pass a string it contains single quotes and this is the error I got:

```
Executing (default): SELECT * FROM users WHERE MATCH (email) AGAINST (''test'*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'test'*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)' at line 1
```

do you know which is the way to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by escaping the quotes:

```
var rawQuery = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE MATCH (email) AGAINST (\"?*\" IN BOOLEAN MODE)";

return sequelize.query(rawQuery, {
        replacements: [text],
        type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
    }).then(function(user) {
        return user;
});
```

Comment: Let's say that it worked but are we sure that the string `test` will match with test in the database or it will go to look for 'test'

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
var rawQuery = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE MATCH (email) AGAINST ("?*" IN BOOLEAN MODE)';
```